# How to doNothing() on void method?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have a method that call a void function in it, and when I use `doNothing()`, it says that void method it's not allowed. How could I `doNothing()` in that specific line?

I'm using this line,

```
when(spyColorSelector.initializeColors(view, "red")).then(doNothing());
```

Comment: Is that the full line, or are you trying to return something?

Comment: I just want that initializeColors(), won't get executed

Comment: When do you want that to happen? Why don't you use an if block?

Answer (score 23):

Use [Stubber](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/stubbing/Stubber.html) syntax :

```
doNothing().when(spyColorSelector).initializeColors(view, "red");
```

And `spyColorSelector` has to be a mock.

---

Edit 1: code example with spy.

This test works (no exception thrown by `initializeColors`) with JUnit 4.12 and Mockito 1.10.19:

```
public class ColorSelectorTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetColors() {
        // Given
        String color = "red";
        View view = mock(View.class);
        ColorSelector colorSelector = new ColorSelector();
        ColorSelector spyColorSelector = spy(colorSelector);
        doNothing().when(spyColorSelector).initializeColors(view, color);

        // When
        LinkedList<Integer> colors = spyColorSelector.getColors(color, view);

        // Then
        assertNotNull(colors);
    }
}

class ColorSelector {

    public LinkedList<Integer> getColors(String color, View view) {
        this.initializeColors(view, color);
        return new LinkedList<>();
    }

    void initializeColors(View view, String color) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Should not be called");
    }
}
```

---

Edit 2: new example without spy.

If you really want `initializeColors` not to be executed in the test, I think there is a design issue in the `ColorSelector` class. The `initializeColors` method should be in another class X, and there would be a dependency of class X in `ColorSelector` class which you could stub in your test (and then no need of spy). Basic example:

```
public class ColorSelectorTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetColors() {
        // Given
        String color = "red";
        View view = mock(View.class);
        ColorSelector colorSelector = new ColorSelector();
        ColorInitializer colorInitializerMock = mock(ColorInitializer.class);
        doNothing().when(colorInitializerMock).initializeColors(view, color);   // Optional because the default behavior of a mock is to do nothing
        colorSelector.colorInitializer = colorInitializerMock;

        // When
        LinkedList<Integer> colors = colorSelector.getColors(color, view);

        // Then
        assertNotNull(colors);
    }
}

class ColorSelector {

    ColorInitializer colorInitializer;

    public LinkedList<Integer> getColors(String color, View view) {
        colorInitializer.initializeColors(view, color);
        return new LinkedList<>();
    }
}

class ColorInitializer {

    public void initializeColors(View view, String color) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that way and still the same. When I debug, the test get into that method.

Comment: How do you initialize your mock? Could you copy paste your whole test?

Comment: `@Test
    public void testGetColors(){

        View view = mock(View.class);

        doNothing().when(spyColorSelector).initializeColors(eq(view), eq("red"));

        LinkedList<Integer> colors = spyColorSelector.getColors("red", view);

        assertNotNull(colors);

    }`

initializeColors() is inside getColors() method

Comment: Ok. I'll answer asap. And how is your spyColorSelector initialized in your test class?

Comment: `ColorSelector spyColorSelector = spy(colorSelector);`

Comment: @JianLeón, can you post the error (and stack trace if there is one) you get?

Comment: I got this in "Edit 1": 

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!

Comment: initializeColors() method, initialize local variables, and It's better for me to leave that way. It makes me easier the way I'm gonna work that funtionality